# Installing IPA file from iOS app

Tags: iphone, installation, jailbreak, ipa

I am trying to install an IPA file from my iOS-app written in Xcode (jailbreak with root access).
For now I am using `installBash.sh` from Installous folder. This script is supposed to do exactly what I want, but it doesn't work properly. The app is launching just fine, but there is no icon, and the app "Document" folder isn't registred properly (the installation process is just wrong).
Does anyone here know how to install an IPA file from an iOS-app in the right way? I heard about `installd` or `MobileInstallation` but I have no idea how to use them.